# What is the best method for creating content in Javascript ready for insertion into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object

I have seen a video tutorial on creating and appending content to the DOM. He suggests that wrting a string like so:

`jQuery('<h2 class=myClass>Hello world</h2>').appendTo('article');`

is sloppy compared to creating an object like so:

`jQuery('<h2></h2>', {text: 'Hello world', class 'myClass'}).appendTo('article');`

I'm still a little unconvinced that this is the best way of doing this. For example, I have a slightly more complex example of DOM creation here:- http://jsperf.com/string-creation-dave Using the suggested method of creating the elements in JS performs alot slower than passing a string of the whole element.

Therefore, is the only benefit of creating the objects with JS readability? How do you create elements in JS? Do you just pass through strings to be inserted into the DOM or do you generate the objects in JS and build up the objects that way?

Comment: I'm no expert, but from what I've heard, one of the reason for using the latter method is to reduce the amount of `HTML` in your `JS` because it doesn't belong there, as well as adds readability. As far as readability goes, you could use backslash as line breaks in the code, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/WYnqx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution is to create the Elements via the `createElement` Method, set its Attributes and insert it into the dom afterwards.

If you have more elements you build the according tree and insert the whole tree into the dom when you are finished.

example [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement):

```
function addElement()
{
  // create a new div element
  // and give it some content
  newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div.

  // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
}
```

but serious, who wants to write such code;) Personally I'd stick with your first example, whatever suits you.

Comment: And since some time ago it also outperforms .innerHTML at least in Chrome.

Comment: @Christoph when you say 'stick with your first example' do you mean the first one on the jsperf test page? Whereby I am building up objects in JS. And do you think this method is tidier and cleaner and so outways the performance benefits of passing through the whole object as a string (as in the second example in the jsperf test)?

Comment: @DaveHaigh I could be wrong, but if you think about it with a real life example: **1.** You have a box with 4 items in it. Task is to lift it on a table. **2.** You have an empty box. Task is to first put 4 items inside that box and then lift it on a table. Which scenario takes less time? Scenario 1. would resemble what you do in your #1 example and 2. would resemble what you do in your #2 example. ( I don't know about the actual mechanics of how jquery assembles each but common sense tells me that #1 is already assembled, and #2 isn't. )

Comment: @DaveHaigh to clarify that: unless you have an application which is absolutely critical about performance, I'd suggest you write it the way it provides the best readability and suits your style best. For normal stuff it won't have any noticable performances changes.